# SQL Error:Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc which executes SQL below. This is giving me run time error: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.' I know that my sub-query is returning more than 1 value, but I'm struggling to find a way to fix it. Basically I'm trying to select all Company Names without 4 or more consecutive characters. Please help.

```
select @flag = 1 from [dbo].[Country] where 1 =( SELECT 1
FROM tabC c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
                    FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
                          from master..spt_values t1)  AS s) mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0))
```

Comment: This will return `1` for each row in TabC where the `not exists` is true, ie multiple lines

Comment: I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  You claim you want "Company Names" but are selecting from a "Country" table.  You are not selecting any names, you are setting a flag.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an aggregate?

```
select MAX(1) from ...
```

or distinct;

```
select distinct 1 from ...
```

to ensure only one row is returned

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @flag INT

select @flag = CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM (
                    select top 95 REPLICATE(CHAR(33 + t1.number), 4) as val
                    from master..spt_values t1
                    where t1.type = 'P'
                ) mul
                WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val, c.CompanyName) > 0) THEN 1
                END
SELECT @Flag
```